# how to add fixed back button in react native

Tags: react-native

I am building react native application for ios and android

i need to add back button in webview to back in the history . 
the project consist of tabscreens for 4 tabs .

app.js file

```js
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import TabScreen from './src/screens/tabscreen'
export default function App() {
  return (
    <TabScreen  />
  );
  }
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Tab, Tabs, TabHeading, Icon, Text,Title,Button,Body,Left,Right } from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabs/tab1';
import Tab2 from './tabs/tab2';
import Tab3 from './tabs/tab3';
import Tab4 from './tabs/tab4';
export default class TabsAdvancedExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        
      <Container>
           
        <Header>
        


        </Header>
        
        <Tabs>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="cart" /><Text>السوق</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="paper" /><Text>تصنيفات</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="home" /><Text>مدونه</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab3 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="add" /><Text>اضف منتجاتك</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab4 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont see whare do you use the webView

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a back button within webView

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BackHandler,
  Platform,
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';

class ExampleWebView extends Component {
  webView = {
    canGoBack: false,
    ref: null,
  }

  onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
      this.webView.ref.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onAndroidBackPress);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com" }}//for example
        ref={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => { this.webView.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack; }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```